# How do I reduce time complexity of the code?

Tags: string, stack, java-7

Below java code is a solution to a [problem in Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-text-editor/problem) - a simple text editor with 4 operations (append, delete, print, undo). Few of the test cases get timed-out and I cannot optimise it further. The `substring` function in java is `O(n)` and I am suspecting that's what I need to improve. Please help with your inputs.

```
    class Element {
    int operation;
    String str;
    Element(int op, String str) {
        this.operation = op;
        this.str = str;
    }
    }
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            int step = sc.nextInt();
            if(step == 1) {
                String str = sc.next();
                append(str);
            } else if(step == 2 ) {
                delete(sc.nextInt());
            } else if(step == 3) {
                print(sc.nextInt());
            } else {
                undo();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void append(String str) {
        stack.push(new Element(1, file));
        file+= str;

    }

    public static void delete(int k) {
        stack.push(new Element(2, file));
        file = file.substring(0, file.length() - k);
    }

    public static void print(int k) {
        System.out.println(file.charAt(k-1));
    }

    public static void undo() {
        if(stack.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Element e = stack.pop();
        file = e.str;
    }

    public static String file = "";
    public static Stack<Element> stack = new Stack<>();
    }
```

Comment: If your code works and you just want to improve it, you're probably better off posting to codereview.stackexchange.com. One hint: consider using a `StringBuilder` rather than a `String`. Your append and delete operations will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried StringBuilder, got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will save you a lot of memory is, rather than pushing the entire string on the undo stack, just push the reverse operation. Consider, you have two operations that modify the string: an append, and deleting the last *k* characters from the string.

The reverse of append is delete, and the reverse of delete is append.

So when you process an append command, the undo operation you push can be:

```
push(2, length-of-string)
```

The way you've written your undo stack, you'll have to save the length as a string, but that's not difficult.

And when you process a delete command, the undo operation you push is:

```
push(1, file.substring(k))
```

Your undo operation, then, performs the operation that you pop from the stack.

This should save you a huge amount of memory, which means the garbage collector won't have to work so hard, and as a result it should be faster.

I still think you should consider `StringBuilder`. The constraints in the problem say that the total length of all strings is less than or equal to 10<sup>6</sup>, which means that you can pre-allocate the `StringBuilder` to 1 megabyte and never have to re-allocate space for it. In addition, the append and delete operations can be done in-place rather than forcing a new `String` instance to be allocated and copied with every operation. With `String`, every time you write something like `file = file + str;`, what happens is this:

1. A new `String` instance is allocated with memory to hold the modified value
2. The existing string is copied to that new memory
3. `str` is appended

All that takes time, and also exercises the garbage collector. Contrast that with `StringBuilder`, which already has the memory allocated. So all it has to do on an append is copy the new string to the buffer. And on a delete, you can just set the length, like this:

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - k); // assuming your StringBuilder is called sb
```

Between using `StringBuilder` and the optimizations to your undo stack, your code should be much faster.

Comment: Really insightful, thanks @Jim. I've made these changes but still get the same result (updated code - http://collabedit.com/jwd8w).

Comment: @akash The class `CharBuffer` provides a O(1) `subSequence` implementation, but sharing the underlying data doesn’t play well with mutating the contents, hence, you’d need to take care when do reuse (e.g. as long as you’re appending, all existing sub-sequences stay valid) and when to copy. An entirely different point is to consider [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayDeque.html): “*This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.*”

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

```java
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sn.nextInt();
        String s1="",s2="";
        int b=0;
        Stack<String> str=new Stack<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int a=sn.nextInt();
            switch(a)
            {
                case 1:
                {     s2=sn.next();
                     str.push(s1);
                     s1=s1+s2;
                     break;
                }
                case 2:
                {    str.push(s1);
                     b=sn.nextInt();
                    
                    s1=s1.substring(0,s1.length()-b);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:            // print char at index 
                {   
                     b=sn.nextInt();
                    b=b-1;
                    System.out.println(s1.charAt(b));
                    break;
                    
                }
                case 4:          // undo process
                {
                    s1=str.peek();
                    str.pop();
                    break;
                    
                }
                

            }
        }
        
    
    }
}
```